# Uninitialized variable trouble C++

Tags: c++, arrays, uninitialized-constant

I keep getting the error message that "'rate' is uninitialized in this function".

Can anyone off the bat see why? I've looked through my code and I'm passing it correctly on my other functions, and the error stems from this function. Any ideas?

```
double compute_rate(int userAge_array[], char sportType_array[], int index)
{
  double rate;
  if (sportType_array[index] == 'f') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 68.95;
    }
    else if (userAge_array[index] > 25) {
      rate = 55.95;
    }
  }
  if (sportType_array[index] == 'g') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 73.95;
    }
    else if (userAge_array[index] > 25) {
      rate = 65.95;
    }
  }
  if (sportType_array[index] == 'h') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 99.95;
    }
    else if (userAge_array[index] > 25) {
      rate = 92.95;
    }
  }

  return rate;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you get to `return rate;` without any of the `rate =` lines?

Comment: Suppose that `sportsType_array[index] == 'a'`

Comment: if sportType_array[index] is something other than f, g, h, say 'z', what will rate be?

Comment: Deleted the "rate =" lines only to still get the same error.

Comment: What if `userAge_array[index] == 25`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning `rate` at the end of the function but it may never initialized because all assignments are inside ifs statements which may not be processed at all.

**Solution:**

assign it at first using some default value that you will accept in case no one of the ifs works:

```
double rate=0.0;
```

Comment: so your solution worked, but when I try to pass rate to another variable in my next function, I recieve a similair error. "variable 'charge' set but not used" you can see the 2nd function here. I should also mention I tried applying your first solution to this variable with no success.  [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ed79f637d0daa0b35a295ddd6136bfdf)

Comment: Maybe you should do something with charge in that code. I mean you compute it but then don't do anything with the computed value.

Comment: Didn't realize I made a cout statement for "rate" rather than "charge" in that function. Thank you, code works now.

Answer (score 1):

If `sportType_array[index]` is not `'f'`, `'g'`, or `'h'`, none of the `if` blocks will execute. You should change these to `if/else if` and then add a final `else` clause when nothing matches.

But more likely, the problem is that `userAge_array[index] == 25`. You set `rate` when it's less than `25` or greater than `25`, but never set `rate` when it's exactly equal to `25`. Try using `else` instead of `else if`, so you cover all cases.

```
double compute_rate(int userAge_array[], char sportType_array[], int index)
{
  double rate;
  if (sportType_array[index] == 'f') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 68.95;
    }
    else {
      rate = 55.95;
    }
  }
  else if (sportType_array[index] == 'g') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 73.95;
    }
    else {
      rate = 65.95;
    }
  }
  else if (sportType_array[index] == 'h') {
    if (userAge_array[index] < 25) {
      rate = 99.95;
    }
    else {
      rate = 92.95;
    }
  }
  else {
      rate = 0.0;
  }

  return rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sportType_array[index]` is not 'f', 'g', or 'h', the function drops straight through to the return, where it returns `rate`, which is not initialized.

What value would you like to return if the values in those arrays are incorrect?  It would be best to set `rate` to that, even if it's not *supposed* to happen.